# FireDac Restore With Multiple Instance Of Firebird

Tags: delphi, firebird, restore, firedac

I have multiple instance of Firebird :

- Firebird 2.5.6 running on port 3050 with ServiceName   FirebirdDerverDefaultInstance
- Firebird 3.04 running on port 3060    with ServiceName
  FirebirdServerFB30

with gbak I do this and it works (I execute gbak directly in my Firebird 3 directory). I can use any random user and random password and it works.

```
gbak -user ADMINxxx -pas adminxxx -c -v -se service_mgr D:\fb30.gbk d:\fb303.gdb
```

With FireDac, I have problem to restore the database when I do this :

```
  ADIBRestore.BackupFiles.Clear;
  ADIBRestore.BackupFiles.Add('D:\fb30.gbk');
  ADIBRestore.Database := 'd:\fb303.gdb';
  ADIBRestore.UserName := 'ADMINxxx';
  ADIBRestore.Password := 'adminxxx';
  ADIBRestore.Host := '127.0.0.1';
  ADIBRestore.Port := '3060';
  ADIBRestore.Restore;
```

this throw me an exception

> [FireDAC][Phys][FB]no permission for CREATE access to DATABASE
>   D:\FB303.GDB failed to create database D:\FB303.GDB unknown ISC error
>   336330835

Is it possible to restore a database with FireDac with User that is not SYSDBA user ?

Comment: are you sure you use FB3 not FB2 in both cases? for example, I do not see in the `gbak` command above any reference to `3060` port, nor to a non-default `IPC` name. You can use SysInternals Process Monitor to check which of the two servers actually creates the database file.

Comment: I'm sure because ODS is good when restored with SYSDBA. I just want owner of the database to be 'ADMINxxx' and not 'SYSDBA'

Comment: That is about the second example. What about the first one, `gbak`? where that comment prohibits use of FB 2 ? Check that the first command does not make FB2's EXE be the one creating the database file. Also, check `grant create database to user/role` command at https://firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-access-sql.html#rnfb30-security-otherprivs

Comment: Firebird 3 added additional privileges, including for creating databases. Given the error, your user doesn't have the privilege to create a database. I suspect that your gbak call is run through the Firebird 2.5 server, and thus works. Try with `-se localhost/3060:service_mgr`, that will probably give the same error. You need to grant the [create database privilege](https://www.firebirdsql.org/file/documentation/release_notes/html/en/3_0/rnfb30-access-sql.html#rnfb30-security-metadataprivs) to your user.

Comment: @MarkRotteveel, exactly. FB3 requires sysdba or owner to be able to do the backup.  Previous versions did not care.

Answer (score 1):

I have been having this issue today as well.  For my case, it turns out that there was an existing connection to the database.  Once I removed all connections, then FireDac worked.  Gbak works even if there are connections to the database.

This is a nuiscance, now that I have invested time in using FireDAC instead of IBObjects.  I am thinking of obtaining exclusive access prior to running the backup.

Answer (score 0):

The user does not have write permission on the specified directory.

Comment: That would result in a different error. This error means that the user doesn't have the CREATE DATABASE privilege (introduced in Firebird 3).